# Get first word out of string-variable

Tags: jquery, regex, string, extract

how can I extract the first word after the first appearance of the character «#» out of a string-variable?

the strings look like this:

```
/* pins */

#a1_pins{
  marker-placement: point;
  …
```

What I want to extract is:

> a1_pins

… the **first word** after the first `#` and before a `{` or a   (space)

Comment: Your string is multiline?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @ojovirtual: Yes, the string is multiline -> have a look at the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will capture everything that starts with a `#` and ends with a space, tab, new line and a `{`

```
\#(.*?)\s|{\g
```

You just need to capture group 1 (`$1`)

Here is a [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3c09i)

Comment: thx. but I had to edit it to `\#.*?\s|{\g` to fetch only one word and without #

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
var a="#a1_pins{ marker-placement: point; …#zxczsxc";
var word=a.split('#')[1].split('{');
console.log(word);
```